# aspnet5 rc1 dnx configuration

Tags: dynamic, configuration, asp.net-core, self-hosting, dnx

In Win 10, IIS 10, AspNet5 RC1, VS 2015, AspNet5 Web Application

1. Dnx, DNVM are installed. In command prompt for dnx --help it shows

--configuration   The configuration to run under

where / what are the different configuration values the can be specified?

2. In AspNet5 web application, self - host, project.json - commands property-

   "commands": {
           "url_1": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001",
           "url_2": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5002"
         }

   Self host same application with different urls - currently - adding separate entry in commands json for each url. Is it possible to add comamnds / set the url value dynamically at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dnx `--configuration` parameter is used for runtime compilation. It can be either `Debug` or `Release` and depending on its value your project will be compiled with specific `compilationOptions` from your project.json file. You can find an example of configuration specific options in project.json [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file) in the *Configurations* section